# How to connect rethinkdb from my laravel project?

Tags: php, node.js, laravel, rethinkdb, laravel-5.4

I have install rethinkdb driver into my laravel project ,but I am unable to connect rethinkdb .If you have any idea regarding this, please suggest

Comment: 'unable' is too broad - what are the symptoms? Any error?

Comment: Yes, you need to give us more details. Are you looking for Eloquent connection, or just a connection>

Comment: InvalidArgumentException with message 'Database [rethinkdb] not configured.

Comment: i modify my env file to DB_CONNECTION=rethinkdb
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_DATABASE=homestead
DB_PORT=28015

Comment: You need to provide code samples. However initially you are doing it wrong, because RethinkDB is not supported.

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mcve] and follow their advice to improve your question, it will help you to get useful answers. SO is not a forum, your question should just be a question; don't include a greeting or "thanks" message. Things like including any error messages your are receiving and saying what you have already tried also go a long way to help people answer your questions.

Comment: this is my modified migration for users      

use duxet\Rethinkdb\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
    
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('password', 60);
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });

Comment: Hi guys finally I have connect rethinkdb with laravel .Actually I need some realtime work with rethinkdb .I use node js for realtime result.